# Why is there module conflict?

Tags: compiler-errors, d

**ma.d**

```
module ma;

struct A{ }
```

**mb.d**

```
module mb;
import ma : A;

struct B{ }
```

**main.d**

```
import ma;
import mb;

void main(){

  A a;
}
```

When compiled:

> main.d(6): Error: ma.A at ma.d(3) conflicts with mb.A at mb.d(2)

In `mb.d` `A` is **not** a public import, so why the error?

Oddly enough, the following code compiles:

**main.d**

```
import mb;

void main(){

  A a;
}
```

So, is this another DMD bug, or have I misunderstood how imports and public imports work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Issue 314 - [module] Static, renamed, and selective imports are always public](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=314)

Comment: @Arlen The bugs in dmd are being fixed at a fast pace these days (as the [changelog](http://d-programming-language.org/changelog.html) shows), but there are still plenty of annoying bugs left in it. The situation is a lot better than it used to be, but if you're expecting a bug-free compiler at this point, you're likely to be disapponted. It's getting there though.

Comment: Walter [just merged](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/190) the fix for this issue.

Comment: @eco And Walter [just reverted](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/190#issuecomment-3317923) it.

Comment: It looks like there was a problem with the fix, but given that a partial fix exists, it probably won't be long before it's fully fixed.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis They released a book over a year ago and told the world D2 is ready for new projects.  My expectations aren't unreasonable at all.  Maybe on their homepage they should leave a text that reads **D is in alpha state** so people don't end up wasting their time.

Comment: @Arlen I understand your frustration. I'm just telling you what the situation is. With the release of TDPL, the language spec was essentially frozen (barring minor tweaks), but the compiler implementation was behind. The number of bugs fixed since then is very high, but there are still bugs left. There is currently a push to fix all known bugs with regards to TDPL, and most (if not all) will be fixed by the next release. D2 _is_ ready for use. You just have to realize that the compiler still has some issues. It hasn't been around as long as compilers like gcc. It is improving rapidly however.